# Excel VBA: Select multiple folders

Tags: vba, excel, directory

I currently have a macro that checks a folder for excel files and runs a few formatting type adjustments (adds columns etc).

The problem is that it will only allow me to select one folder and check in there. There are lots of folders that I need it to check in which all exist within the same directory.

I cannot select more than one folder to check in, even by adjusting the AllowMultiSelect to True. How can I modify this code so that it will allow me to select all folders within a directory?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog


  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

  NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

  myExtension = "*.xls"

  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  Do While myFile <> ""
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & myFile)

      DoEvents

        'Formatting adjustments etc go here

      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

      DoEvents

      myFile = Dir

  Loop

  MsgBox "Complete."



End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242714(v=vs.60).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216(v=vs.71).aspx should help

Answer (score 0):

I think I come up with some better solution than manually selecting all the folders. You said that all of your files are in some directory, which have some subfolders inside. With below code, you will loop through every file in folder you pick. You will store every formating logics in Formatting sub.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim MyPath As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With


    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call GetAllFiles(MyPath, objFSO)
    Call GetAllFolders(MyPath, objFSO)

  MsgBox "Complete."

NextCode:
End Sub
Sub GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            Formatting (objFile.Path)
    Next objFile
End Sub

Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        Call GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
        Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
    Next objSubFolder
End Sub

Sub Formatting(strFile As String)
Dim wb As Workbook
    If Right(strFile, 3) = "xls" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & myFile)
        DoEvents

        'Formatting adjustments etc go here

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        DoEvents
        myFile = Dir
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this concept?  You recursively map to all files in all folders, and create a schema of your whole folder structure.  Then, control each file, based on each folder path.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListAllFiles()
        searchForFiles "C:\your_path_here\", "writefilestosheet", "*.*", True, True
    End Sub

    Sub processOneFile(ByVal aFilename As String)
        Debug.Print aFilename
    End Sub

    Sub writeFilesToSheet(ByVal aFilename As String)
        With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = aFilename
            End With
    End Sub


    Private Sub processFiles(ByVal DirToSearch As String, _
                ByVal ProcToCall As String, _
                ByVal FileTypeToFind As String)
            Dim aFile As String
            aFile = Dir(DirToSearch & FileTypeToFind)
            Do While aFile <> ""
                Application.Run ProcToCall, DirToSearch & aFile
                aFile = Dir()
                Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub processSubFolders(ByVal DirToSearch As String, _
                ByVal ProcToCall As String, _
                ByVal FileTypeToFind As String, _
                ByVal SearchSubDir As Boolean, _
                ByVal FilesFirst As Boolean)

    Dim aFolder As String, SubFolders() As String

    ReDim SubFolders(0)

    aFolder = Dir(DirToSearch, vbDirectory)

        Do While aFolder <> ""

            If aFolder <> "." And aFolder <> ".." Then

                If (GetAttr(DirToSearch & aFolder) And vbDirectory) _
                        = vbDirectory Then
                    SubFolders(UBound(SubFolders)) = aFolder
                    ReDim Preserve SubFolders(UBound(SubFolders) + 1)
                    End If
                    End If
                aFolder = Dir()
                Loop

            If UBound(SubFolders) <> LBound(SubFolders) Then
                Dim i As Long
                For i = LBound(SubFolders) To UBound(SubFolders) - 1
                    searchForFiles _
                        DirToSearch & SubFolders(i), _
                        ProcToCall, FileTypeToFind, SearchSubDir, FilesFirst
                    Next i
                End If

        End Sub

    Sub searchForFiles(ByVal DirToSearch As String, ByVal ProcToCall As String, _
            Optional ByVal FileTypeToFind As String = "*.*", _
            Optional ByVal SearchSubDir As Boolean = False, _
            Optional ByVal FilesFirst As Boolean = False)
        On Error GoTo ErrXIT
        If Right(DirToSearch, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then _
            DirToSearch = DirToSearch & Application.PathSeparator

    If FilesFirst Then processFiles DirToSearch, ProcToCall, FileTypeToFind
    If SearchSubDir Then processSubFolders DirToSearch, ProcToCall, _
        FileTypeToFind, SearchSubDir, FilesFirst

        If Not FilesFirst Then _
            processFiles DirToSearch, ProcToCall, FileTypeToFind
        Exit Sub
    ErrXIT:
        MsgBox "Fatal error: " & Err.Description & " (Code=" & Err.Number & ")"
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
```